# UI in SNAP program not showing in the right position

Tags: debian, gnome, gui, window

I have a problem with the SNAP (from step) program but I suspect it is related to my machine settings and not to the program itself as it is written in Java and works in other OS and computers.

In summary, the UI is not well aligend and not always showing.
I have the same problem in two linux machines:
1. Debian 10, Gnome 3.34 and Wayland
2. Debian 9, Gnome 3.22 and X11

[image]

The labels on the left menu are somewhat hidden (height not matching font size?)
The top window is not showing many UI components that should be there

Two images showing the UI components as they should look like
[image]
[image]

tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a problem on both windows and linux in High DPI resolutions
The problem was solved changing to a non-default theme going to
**Tools** -> **Options** -> **Appearance** in the program itself.

There are flags in the settings file design to solve the issue but they do not currently work

source: https://forum.step.esa.int/t/snap-on-4k-hidpi-screens/3001/6